# what does the law of mapping mean?(Functional programing in Scala)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

On page 111, the mapping law reasons like below:

- Line1: `map(unit(x))(f) == unit(f(x))`
- Line2: `map(unit(x))(id) == unit(id(x))`
- Line3: `map(unit(x))(id) == unit(x)`
- Line4: `map(y)(id) == y`

What confuses me is the transition from Line2 to Line3, it seems I have missed something, can someone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

It works this way because `id(x) == x`, so:

`map(unit(x))(id) == unit(id(x)) == unit(x)`

Comment: why id(x) == x ? what does id mean here?

Comment: `id` is an identity function, that returns exactly same value as given, so for example `id(5) == 5`.